# How do I add a build step to a Jenkins job programmatically?

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins

I am writing a Jenkins plugin, and I want it to create a new job (in the `perform(...)` method, as a build step).

I know that I can create a job like this:

```
 FreeStyleProject proj =
       Hudson.getInstance().createProject(FreeStyleProject.class, "New job");
```

and I can add properties to it using `proj.addProperty(someJobProperty)`.

How can I then also add a build step to the project, programmatically, like the properties? Specifically, I would like to add an *Execute shell* and *Copy Artifact* build step.

I have been looking through the Jenkins JavaDoc, especially the [Job](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Job.html) page, and I haven't been able to find anything that would help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project has a method `getBuildersList()` which returns the list of all the build steps. You can add a build step to the project by simply adding a build step to the list returned by this method. The object you are adding to the list must be a `Builder`.

I did it like this (using the plugin from the Jenkins HelloWorld tutorial as an example):

```
proj.getBuildersList().add(new HelloWorldBuilder("Bobbly"));
```

This adds a Hello World build step to the project.

Similarly, there is a `getPublishersList()` method which returns the list of all the post-build steps and contains `Publisher` objects.